# Remove the outline of an oval in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

By default, the circle I draw on a canvas has a black outline. I'm trying not to use a color, but somehow make the outline disappear.

```
import tkinter

class Draw:
    def __init__(self):
        self._root_window = tkinter.Tk()
        self._canvas = tkinter.Canvas(master = self._root_window,
                                  width = 500, height = 500,
                                  background = '#1E824C')
        self._canvas.pack()
        self._canvas.create_oval(100,100,250,250, fill = 'white')
        self._root_window.mainloop

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Draw()
```

[image]

Comment: Please, show us your code

Comment: Hi, sorry for the lack of code. It is now provided.

Comment: Did you tried `disabledoutline` option?

Comment: @Samuel : How am I able to use that? I understand it goes inside the create_oval parameter. The only problem I have is not knowing how to use it and the tkinter documentation wasn't too clear on it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Add `outline=""` parameter to `create_oval` method.

Then you can create oval link that:

```
self._canvas.create_oval(100,100,250,250, fill = 'white', outline="")
```

Comment: I did not need to add borderwidth, however this solved my problem!

Comment: `borderwidth` has nothing to do with objects that are drawn on the canvas. It only affects the border of the widget itself.

Answer (score 3):

Apart from using `outline =""` or `outline = "white"`, you can specify the width of outline to be `0`  because by default it is set to `1`.

Add **`width = 0`** as an option when you create the oval:

```
   self._canvas.create_oval(100,100,250,250, fill = 'white', width=0)
```

## Demo

[image]